# STL: writing "where" operator for a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I need to find the indexes in the vector based on several boolean predicates.

ex:

```
vector<float> v;
vector<int> idx;

idx=where( bool_func1(v), bool_func2(v), ... );
```

What is the way to declare `**where**` function, in order to use the several user defined boolean functions over the vector?

thanks
Arman.

**Edit after one week**

I did some complex solutions with templates. But in reality one can use already predefined `valarray` for my tasks. Here is the code snippet maybe one can find it useful:

```
  double dr=Rc/(double)Nbins, r;
  sigma.resize(Nbins);
  rr=sigma;
  valarray<double> vz(&data.vz[0], data.vz.size());
  double mvel=vz.sum()/(double)vz.size();
  for(size_t i=0l;i<Nbins;i++)
   {
   r=dr*i;
   valarray<bool> ids = (dist < r+dr) && (dist > r);//The magic valarray<bool>
   if(ids.max())
    {
    valarray<double> d=vz[ids];//we can use indirect operation.
    d-=mvel;
    d=pow(d,2.0);
    sigma[i]= sqrt(d.sum()/(double)d.size());
    rr[i]=r;
    cout<<i<<") "<<r<<" "<<sigma[i]<<endl;
    }
   }
```

Comment: not certain I understand what "where" should be doing and returning considering it can have multiple predicates and multiple different vectors. 
Can you show us a simple input and output ?

Comment: @Max I assume it should take *n* functions and return a vector of integers

Comment: It's not at all clear how you want the predicates combined. Are you looking for an element in the vector where all the predicates are true, or the first one that's true, or something else entirely?

Comment: @Yacoby: yes, thanks for pointing it. I need to put several constrains on a given vector and return the indexes.

Comment: @Jerry: For example I need to know: id=where(v < 10.0 && v>1.0); and somewhere later I would like to know: id=where(v < fun(v));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your bool_xxx functions actually functors of a specific kind of type (tag dispatching would be enough).  Then override || and && for them such that these operators return a bool_and, or bool_or.  Then you can use your bool_ predicates like so:

```
std::find_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), bool_x1() || bool_x2() && (bool_x3() || bool_x4() && bool_x5()));
```

If you're tempted to write a "where" function then you apparently want to do this more than once with a different set of bool_xxx functions.  Even if you know that you want a certain type of composition now, you may as well make it as universal as possible.  This is how I'd do it.

Edit:

Based on this comment: *@Jerry: For example I need to know: id=where(v < 10.0 && v>1.0); and somewhere later I would like to know: id=where(v < fun(v));* you may be better off with boost::lambda:

```
namespace l = boost::lambda;
std::find_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), l::_1 < 10.0 && l::_1 > 1.0);
std::find_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), l::_1 < l::bind(fun, l::_1));
```

Or, if you hate lambda or aren't allowed to use it...or just want a very slightly nicer syntax (but inability to use functions directly) then just make your own placeholder type and override it to return bool_xxx functors on operators <, >, etc...

Edit2: Here's an untested where that returns a vector of iterators to all objects matching:

```
template < typename ForwardIter, typename Predicate >
std::vector<ForwardIter> where(ForwardIter beg, ForwardIter end, Predicate pred)
{
  ForwardIter fit = std::find_if(beg,end,pred);
  if (fit == end) return std::vector<ForwardIter>();

  ForwardIter nit = fit; ++nit;
  std::vector<ForwardIter> collection = where(nit,end,pred);
  collection.push_front(fit);
  return collection;
}
```

It's recursive and could be slow on some implementations but there's one way to do it.

Comment: I could be wrong but doesn't find_if return an iterator to the *first* match? Arman wants a list of *all* matching indices.

Comment: @Job: You're right, but for an iterator `it` into a vector `v`, the index can be computed as `it-v.begin()`.

Comment: @Arman: If you think this is impressive wait until you see the compiler error messages when you do something wrong with this. There's some very heavy template magic going on behind the scenes, and when the compiler pukes that out for you, it's quite disgusting. (If you're using a compiler that supports C++1x lambda you might be better off using that. There is a reason the std committee built it into the language rather than using their preferred method of adding a library.)

Comment: @Noah Roberts: Now with lambda it works. I would like to pass to my where function the array of lambda closures, What type is  "l::_1 < l::bind(fun, l::_1)"?

Comment: @sbi: no , I dont have any compiler errors, it compiles fine:)

Comment: @job - just run find on fit + 1 if fit != vect.end() and append the result.  So Arman could implement where like above by filling in the sig "template < typename It, typename Fun > where (It beg, It end, Fun pred)..." with a loop that calls find_if repeatedly until it reaches end.  Then it would be used like: "where(vect.begin(), vect.end(), l::_1 < 10.0 && l::_1 > 1.0)".  I think I'd rename it to something like "collect_if".  Or maybe a different algorithm like std::accumulate with an accumulator that just appends when the pred is matched...

Comment: @Arman - it's undefined.  Make it a template parameter and then you can use any sort of predicate or binder.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: collect_if sounds nicer:) thanks I will rename it.

Comment: @Arman, @Noah Roberts: collect_if would be more simply written as the infamous missing copy_if. Unless you have pressing performance reasons to do it this way, I'd go with standard implementations of copy_if that you can find online. See: http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppCopy_if.htm for one. transform_if listed below is very similar.

Comment: @Owen - I agree.  I like the transform_if idea to get the index; I wrote my example before I saw that.  A copy_if might also be valid with the one caveat that it's going to copy what it runs into (assuming it lives up to its name) instead of refer to the elements directly.  Depending on use this could either be exactly what is needed or exactly not.  Since Arman was looking for indexes it may very well be that a "collect_if" (or the transform_if) is what they need, but it's definitely a preferable option to look at if it meets their needs.

Comment: @Owen - of course, remove_copy_if !pred could be a better option than even finding and using a copy_if since it's already there.

Comment: @Owen S.: thanks for the link. 
Sorry, but your web site background is very disturbing. It is very hard to read.

Comment: @Noah Roberts just a small note: fit+1 will actually not work for forward iterators since iterator addition is only defined for random access iterators. use std::advance instead.

Comment: @Noah: What's the advantage of doing this recursively (and thereby repeatedly copying the resulting container)? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Noah: You mean you don't know an advantage or you don't know an iterative implementation? An iterative implementation ought to be a three-liner and  wouldn't needlessly copy the result. In both the recursive implementation has a disadvantage.

Comment: @Noah: Well, turns out I was wrong. It's a [four-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999537/3001760#3001760).

Comment: @Aman: lol, didn't even notice the background on that page the first time around! Not my choice either.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: re: remove_copy_if: I've read that the lack of copy_if was a simple oversight, so I think of it as equivalent to a standard algorithm. I wouldn't prefer remove_copy_if myself unless it actually made the code clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a predicated version of `transform`, if there were one.  There's not one, but it is very easy to write:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryFunction, class Predicate>
OutputIterator transform_if(InputIterator first, 
                            InputIterator last, 
                            OutputIterator result, 
                            UnaryFunction f, 
                            Predicate pred)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if( pred(*first) )
            *result++ = f(*first);
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Then you would need a way to make a composite of multiple predicates, so that you could express something like `find_if( begin, end, condition1 && condition2 )`.  This, again, is easy to write:

```
template<typename LHS, typename RHS> struct binary_composite : public std::unary_function<Gizmo, bool>
{
    binary_composite(const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs) : lhs_(&lhs), rhs_(&rhs) {};

    bool operator()(const Gizmo& g) const
    {
        return lhs_->operator()(g) && rhs_->operator()(g);
    }
private:
    const LHS* lhs_;
    const RHS* rhs_;
};
```

Finally you need a gizmo that `transform_if` uses to convert an object reference to an object pointer.  Surprise, surprise, easy to write...

```
template<typename Obj>  struct get_ptr : public std::unary_function<Obj, Obj*>
{
    Obj* operator()(Obj& rhs) const { return &rhs; }
};
```

Let's put this all together with a concrete example.  `Gizmo` below is the object that you have a collection of.  We have 2 predicates `find_letter` and `find_value` that we want to search for matches to in our main `vector`.  `transform_if` is the predicated version of `transform`, `get_ptr` converts an object reference to a pointer, and `binary_composite` strings together the two composites.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Gizmo
{
    string name_;
    int value_;
};

struct find_letter : public std::unary_function<Gizmo, bool>
{
    find_letter(char c) : c_(c) {}
    bool operator()(const Gizmo& rhs) const { return rhs.name_[0] == c_; }
private:
    char c_;
};

struct find_value : public std::unary_function<Gizmo, int>
{
    find_value(int v) : v_(v) {};
    bool operator()(const Gizmo& rhs) const { return rhs.value_ == v_; }
private:
    int v_;
};

template<typename LHS, typename RHS> struct binary_composite : public std::unary_function<Gizmo, bool>
{
    binary_composite(const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs) : lhs_(&lhs), rhs_(&rhs) {};

    bool operator()(const Gizmo& g) const
    {
        return lhs_->operator()(g) && rhs_->operator()(g);
    }
private:
    const LHS* lhs_;
    const RHS* rhs_;
};

template<typename LHS, typename RHS> binary_composite<LHS,RHS> make_binary_composite(const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs)
{
    return binary_composite<LHS, RHS>(lhs, rhs);
}


template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryFunction, class Predicate>
OutputIterator transform_if(InputIterator first, 
                            InputIterator last, 
                            OutputIterator result, 
                            UnaryFunction f, 
                            Predicate pred)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if( pred(*first) )
            *result++ = f(*first);
    }
    return result; 
}

template<typename Obj>  struct get_ptr : public std::unary_function<Obj, Obj*>
{
    Obj* operator()(Obj& rhs) const { return &rhs; }
};


int main()
{   
    typedef vector<Gizmo> Gizmos;
    Gizmos gizmos;
    // ... fill the gizmo vector

    typedef vector<Gizmo*> Found;
    Found found;
    transform_if(gizmos.begin(), gizmos.end(), back_inserter(found), get_ptr<Gizmo>(), binary_composite<find_value,find_letter>(find_value(42), find_letter('a')));

    return 0;

}
```

---

### EDIT:

Based on [sbi's iterative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999537/stl-writing-where-operator-for-a-vector/3001760#3001760), here's a predicated version of `copy`, which is more in line with the general STL paradigm, and can be used with `back_insert_iterator` to accomplish what's wanted in this case.  It will give you a `vector` of object, not iterators or indexes, so the `transform_if` I posted above is still better for this use than `copy_if`.  But here it is...

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class Predicate>
OutputIterator copy_if(InputIterator first, 
                       InputIterator last, 
                       OutputIterator result, 
                       Predicate pred)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if( pred(*first) )
            *result++ = *first;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks John for pointing the transform_if, it is already long time in my utility collection, I use it a lot and seems to me it is a magic function:)(after your post )

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem that could much easier be solved in an declarative language like Prolog. I gave it a try in C++ anyway:

```
typedef float type;
typedef bool (*check)(type);

std::vector<int> where(const std::vector<type>& vec,
                       const std::vector<check>& checks)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        bool allGood = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < checks.size(); j++)
        {
            if (!checks[j](vec[i]))
            {
                allGood = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allGood)
            ret.push_back(i);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which indexes you want. Is this what you are trying to acheive:

```
//Function pointer declaration
typedef bool (*Predicate)(const std::vector<float>& v);

//Predicates
bool bool_func1(const std::vector<float>& v)
{
    //Implement
    return true;
}

bool bool_func2(const std::vector<float>& v)
{
    //Implement
    return true;
}


std::vector<int> where_func(const std::vector<float>& v,
                const std::vector<Predicate>& preds)
{
    std::vector<int>  idxs;
    std::vector<Predicate>::const_iterator iter = preds.begin();
    std::vector<Predicate>::const_iterator eiter = preds.end();
    for(; iter != eiter; ++iter)
    {
        if((*iter)(v))
        {
            idxs.push_back(eiter - iter);
        }   
    }

    return idxs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename Vector, typename T> std::vector<int> where(const std::vector<Vector>& vec, T t) {
    std::vector<int> results;
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (t(vec[i])
            results.push_back(i)
    }
    return results;
}
```

Overload for additional function object arguments as you wish. Use:

```
template<typename T> struct AlwaysAccept {
    bool operator()(const T& t) { return true; }
};
std::vector<float> floats;
// insert values into floats here
std::vector<int> results = where(floats, AlwaysAccept<float>());
```

Noah Robert's solution is nice, but I'm not wholly sure how I could make that work.