# How to copy_if from map to vector?

Tags: c++, copy, c++11

I'd like to copy values that match a predicate (equal ints) from a `map<string,int>` to a `vector<int>`.

This is what I tried:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > v;
    std::map< std::string, int > m;

    m[ "1" ] = 1;
    m[ "2" ] = 2;
    m[ "3" ] = 3;
    m[ "4" ] = 4;
    m[ "5" ] = 5;

    std::copy_if( m.begin(), m.end(), v.begin(),
                  [] ( const std::pair< std::string,int > &it )
                  {
                    return ( 0 == ( it.second % 2 ) );
                  }
                  );
}
```

The error message from g++ 4.6.1 is :

```
error: cannot convert 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>' to 'int' in assignment
```

Is there a way to adjust the example to do the above copy?

Comment: This is an excellent question that's I'm surprised isn't asked more often.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `boost::range` it is as easy as:

```
boost::push_back(
    v,
    m | boost::adaptors::map_values 
      | boost::adaptors::filtered([](int val){ return 0 == (val % 2); }));
```

Comment: `boost::range` needs more love. The simple pipeline concept is just too good to pass in programming.

Comment: boost::copy + std::back_inserter is quite ugly. If you use boost.range then `boost::push_back(v, m | map_values | filtered([](int val){ return 0 == (val % 2); }));` is clearer and shorter IMHO.

Comment: This also seams to be the optimal solution (regarding the speed).

Comment: @ThomasPetit: Yeah, I forgot about that one! Fixed.

Comment: Just a small question : it should be `boost::mpl::push_back`, no?

Comment: Found it. So, you are using this one : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/push_back.html

Answer (score 12):

### Problem

The copy fails because you're copying from a `map::iterator` which iterates over `pair<string const,int>` to a `vector::iterator` which iterates over `int`.

### Solution

Replace `copy_if` with `for_each` and do a `push_back` on your vector.

### Example

```
std::for_each( m.begin(), m.end(),
    [&v] ( std::pair< std::string const,int > const&it ) {
        if ( 0 == ( it.second % 2 ) ) {
            v.push_back(it.second);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Instead of writing a loop and pushing each element back by hand, use `transform`.  That's what it's for.

Comment: @JohnDibling: How would you do the even-number filtering with transform? AFAIK it is one-to-one, so you always get the same number of elements in input and output.

Comment: @Kleist:  Use `transform_if`.  See my answer.

Comment: You need to modify your lambda capture clause to `[&v]` in order to access the vector in the enclosing scope.

Comment: "*The copy fails because you're copying from a `map::iterator` which iterates over `pair<string,int>`*" No, it iterates over `pair<string const, int>` -- the key type of an associative container is always `const`.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler error is actually quite succinct:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>' to 'int' in assignment
```

And that's exactly what the problem is.  The `map` you're copying from has iterators that dereference to a `pair<KEY,VALUE>`, and there's no way to implicitly *transform* a `pair<KEY,VALUE>` to just a `VALUE`.

Because of this, you can't use `copy` or `copy_if` to copy from a `map` to a `vector`; but the Standard Library does provide an algorithm you can use, creatively called `transform`.  `transform` is very similar to `copy` in that it takes two source iterators and a destination iterator.  The difference is `transform` also takes a unary function that does the actual transformation.  Using a C++11 lambda, you can copy the entire contents of a `map` to a `vector` like this:

```
transform( m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v), [] (const MyMap::value_type& vt)
{
  return vt.second;
});
```

What if you don't want to copy the entire contents of the `map`, but only some elements meeting certian criteria?  Simple, just use `transform_if`.

What's that, you say?  There is no `transform_if` in the Standard Library?  Well yeah, you do have a point there.  Frustratingly, there is no `transform_if` in the Standard Library.  However [writing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999537/stl-writing-where-operator-for-a-vector/3000008#3000008) is a simple enough task.  Here's the code:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryFunction, class Predicate>
OutputIterator transform_if(InputIterator first, 
                            InputIterator last, 
                            OutputIterator result, 
                            UnaryFunction f, 
                            Predicate pred)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if( pred(*first) )
            *result++ = f(*first);
    }
    return result; 
}
```

As you might expect, using `transform_if` is like taking `copy_if` and mashing it together with `transform`.  Here's some psudo-code to demonstrate:

```
transform_if( m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v),
  [] (const MyMap::value_type& vt) // The UnaryFunction takes a pair<K,V> and returns a V
  {
    return vt.second;
  }, [] (const MyMap::value_type& vt) // The predicate returns true if this item should be copied
  {
     return 0 == (vt.second%2);
  } );
```

Comment: It is shorter. The transformation from map-elements to map-values occurs through a named library call, and the filtering is done on the result of that transformation (rather than repeating the transformation). The whole code is composed of simple orthogonal elements, instead of using a monolithic `transform_if` function which does multiple things at once. It avoids the need to specify multiple iterators for a single input range.

Comment: And this is where `views` are sorely missed. If we only had a `filter_view` then it would be as simple as chaining the filtering and the transform operation.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot understand why the simple for loop solution is not the preferred approach, for this problem

```
for (std::map< std::string, int >::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it )
{
   if ((it->second % 2) == 0)
      v.push_back(it->second);
}
```

Except that it makes the code more readable it performs better. I wrote a simple benchmark to see how a for loop performs compared to the other proposed solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map< std::string, int > m;
    std::vector<int> v;

    // Fill the map with random values...
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    for (unsigned i=0; i<10000; ++i)
    {
      int r = rand();
      std::stringstream out;
      out << r;
      std::string s = out.str();

      m[s] = r;
    } 

    /////////// FOR EACH ////////////////////

    clock_t start1 = clock();
    for (unsigned k=0; k<10000; k++)
    {
      v.clear();
      std::for_each( m.begin(), m.end(),
      [&v] ( const std::pair< std::string,int > &it ) {
      if ( 0 == ( it.second % 2 ) ) {
          v.push_back(it.second);
      }
      }
      );
    }
    clock_t end1=clock();
    std::cout << "Execution Time for_each : " << (end1-start1) << std::endl;

    /////////// TRANSFORM ////////////////////

    clock_t start2 = clock();
    for (unsigned k=0; k<10000; k++)
    {
      v.clear();
      std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v),
            [] ( const std::pair< std::string,int > &it )
            {
              return it.second;
            });
      v.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int value){ return (value % 2) != 0; }),
    v.end());
    }
    clock_t end2 = clock();
    std::cout << "Execution Time transform : " << (end2-start2) << std::endl;


     /////////// SIMPLE FOR LOOP ////////////////////
    clock_t start3 = clock();
    for (unsigned k=0; k<10000; k++)
    {
      v.clear();
      for (std::map< std::string, int >::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it )
      {
    if ((it->second % 2) == 0)
      v.push_back(it->second);
      }
    }
    clock_t end3=clock();
    std::cout << "Execution Time Simple For Loop : " << (end3-start3) << std::endl;

}
```

The results I got are the following:

```
Execution Time for_each : 7330000
Execution Time transform : 11090000
Execution Time Simple For Loop : 6530000
```

Comment: This does not do the filtering (`( 0 == ( it.second % 2 ) )`).

Comment: You didn't enable optimization. Your numbers are right for default settings, but once you enable optimization, the numbers are quite comparable. If you are using g++, use `-O3`. With optimization enabled, I got the version using transform the fastest

Comment: With Optimization i still get better results for the for loop for_each : 3890000
transform : 4000000
For Loop : 2940000

Answer (score 2):

`std::copy_if` won't allow you to transfer from one type to another, only to filter what to copy.

You could use `std::transform` to get rid of the key and then use `std::remove_if`:

```
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(v),
                  [] ( const std::pair< std::string,int > &it )
                  {
                    return it.second;
                  });
  v.erase(
      std::remove_if(
          v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int value){ return (value % 2) != 0; }),
      v.end());
```

However, a plain for loop would be more efficient and a lot easier to read.

Comment: Better, but `transform_if` would be better still.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you just want to retrieve the associated values from the `map`, not the keys.

The SGI version of STL has `select1st` and `select2nd` iterators for this kind of task.

Personally, however, I don't think this should really be done with copy -- you're transforming the data, not copying it. As such, I'd advise using `std::transform` with a functor to return the second item in the pair.