# Best way to emulate something like conditional_back_inserter?

Tags: c++, stl

I wanted to replace the loop with an *algorithm* in the following code

```
int numbers[] = { ... };
vector<int> output;

for( int* it = numbers+from; it != numbers+to ; ++it ) 
{
    int square = func( *it );
    if( predicate(square) )
    {
         output.push_back(square);
    }
}
```

The program is meant to transform the values and copy them to a destination if a condition occurs.

- I could not use `std::copy_if` because that would not apply a transformation.
- I could not use `std::transform` because that lacks a predicate
- It is not even a good idea to write a *`transform_copy_if()`* , because of the intermediate copy of the transformed variable.

It looks like my only hope is to create a `conditional_back_insert_iterator`. Then I could have a pretty decent call like:

```
int numbers[] = { ... };
vector<int> output;

std::transform(numbers+from, numbers+to, 
               conditional_back_inserter(predicate, output),   
               func);
```

**Is this solution the best way to treat such cases ?** I couldn't even google for conditional inserters, so I am worried I'm on the wrong path.

I could also imagine that I could implement an alternative solution such as

```
std::copy_if( transform_iterator<func>(numbers+from), 
              transform_iterator<func>(numbers+to), 
              back_inserter(output) );
```

(which reminds me of an example of *filter_iterators* in boost)
but that does not offer readability.

Comment: There are too many (useful) things that don't exist in the Standard Library.

Comment: BTW, I've [a library called pipeline](http://snawaz.github.io/foam/pipeline.html), using which you can write this: `auto results = numbers | transform(func) | filter(pred);`

Comment: I'd use `copy_if` and write a transforming iterator. Boost's [`function_output_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) may be relevant.

Comment: @BoBTFish can you give me a (rough) sample of that?  I'm really interested on how it would look from the user's point of view (readability, and how easy it would be to call it)

Comment: Have a look at John Diblings answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137869/how-to-copy-if-from-map-to-vector/8138307)

Comment: @TomKnapen: I'm afraid this is not completely relevant. If I used a `transform_if()` I would have to call the transformation function inside the predicate as well.

Comment: `OutputIterator::container_type::value_type temp = f(*first); if (pred(temp)) *result++ = temp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think creating your own iterator is the way to go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
class conditional_back_insert_iterator
    : public std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T>>
{
private:
    using Base       = std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T>>;
    using Container  = std::vector<T>;
    using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
public:
    template<class F>
    conditional_back_insert_iterator(Container& other, F&& pred)
        :  Base(other), c(other), predicate(std::forward<F>(pred))
    { }

    conditional_back_insert_iterator<T>& operator*()
    { return *this; }

    conditional_back_insert_iterator<T>&
        operator=(const value_type& val) const
    {
        if (predicate(val))
            c.push_back(val);
        return *this;
    }

    conditional_back_insert_iterator<T>&
        operator=(value_type&& val) const
    {
        if (predicate(val))
            c.push_back(std::move(val));
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Container& c;
    std::function<bool (const value_type&)> predicate;
};

template<
    class Container,
    class F,
    class value_type = typename Container::value_type
>
conditional_back_insert_iterator<value_type>
    conditional_back_inserter(Container& c, F&& predicate)
{
    return conditional_back_insert_iterator<value_type>(c, std::forward<F>(predicate));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::vector<int> to;

    auto is_even = [] (int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; };

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), conditional_back_inserter(to, is_even));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <class Container, class Pred>
class conditional_insert_iterator 
    : public std::iterator< std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void >
{
public:
    explicit conditional_insert_iterator(Container& c, Pred p) : container(&c), pred(p) {}
   conditional_insert_iterator& operator=(typename Container::const_reference value) {
    if (pred(value))
        container->push_back(value);
    return *this;
}

    conditional_insert_iterator& operator*() {return *this;}
    conditional_insert_iterator& operator++() {return *this;}
    conditional_insert_iterator& operator++(int) {return *this;}
private:
    Container* container;
    Pred pred;
};

template< class Container, class Pred>
conditional_insert_iterator<Container, Pred> conditional_inserter( Container& c, Pred pred )
{
    return conditional_insert_iterator<Container, Pred>(c, pred);
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> in = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    vector<int> out;
    transform(in.begin(), in.end(),
              conditional_inserter(out, [](int i) { return i%2 == 0;}), 
              [](int i) { return i + 2;});
    for (auto i : out)
        cout << i << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```